# Is it possible to install Samba 3 on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, centos7, samba

Trying to address a compatibility problem with Samba 4, that comes with CentOS 7, I consider downgrading to Samba 3.

However, based on this page https://pkgs.org/download/samba, and elsewhere I have looked, I can not find a Samba 3 version where it is indicated that it is build for CentOS 7.

Can I simply take the latest Samba 3 RPM package for CentOS 6 and install this on CentoOS 7?

Or is there another and better way to install Samba 3 on Centos 7?

Comment: No, you can't install the EL6 package on EL7. Samba's dependency list is extensive and you would likely run into many package conflicts. CentOS 6 maintenance EOL is Nov 2020 - you could either install the older OS, or try to build the Samba 3 source into your own binary package

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I will probably try out building from source, and update here with the result.

Comment: Tried to install Samba 3 RPMs on CentOS 7, but the dependency checks enforced by `yum` prevented this, and I could not find or install the prerequisite packages.  Also tried to find Samba 3 source, but with no luck.  Then as a test, tried to compile Samba 4 source, but the list of missing dependencies shown during `./configure` is extensive, so I assume the challenges for compiling Samba 3 will be even bigger... Guess I will end up installing CentOS 6 with Samba 3 in a Docker, and then present that CentOS 6 as a new host.

Answer (score 2):

1. find the centos6 SRPM for samba3 on [vault][(vault.centos.org)
2. `rpm -i` that source RPM on centos7
3. you now have source and a `spec` file, which can be used as a guide to building samba3.

But we need to both agree that a samba4 problem on centos7 is not going to be accurate replicated or confirmed by building a different version of the software and smelling whether that works.

I recommend opening a new issue - here, samba.org, or with Red Hat - and letting us know what issue you're seeing so we can address the issue.  Using us like marionettes for a bit of lifting to help explore a corner case miles away from your problem means we're unable to spot and help you overcome issues that you may not be aware you have.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I actually ended up posting a specific question related to this in https://superuser.com/questions/1307830/cant-make-get-wd-tv-media-player-to-connect-to-samba-smb-after-upgrade-from-3-to, and ended up finding a solution that did not require install of Samba 3.  But I left this question here, since it got a number of upvotes, which indicates that other users found it useful, probably based on the related comments, that actually answer the question.